# onclick send data to another page

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im trying to use an onclick function to send a url to another page in php. I have a similar function to add but this function is to remove but it does nothing, just removes the button from the page. No errors are visible in the console either.

This is my function:

```
function remove(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'cart.php?remove='+id,
        success: function ( response ) {
          alert( 'removed: '+id );
        }
      });
}
```

I have tried just alert('some text'); but this does the same thing. my button is:

```
onclick="remove(<?php echo $value; ?>)"
```

The button is on cart.php which is being included on main.php

Comment: try adding error: function(e){ alert(e.responseText) ; } which will tell the error if success is not getting called..

Comment: I have tried this, no luck it didnt give me an alert but in console said this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I think it may have sytax error, try with below code
function remove(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'cart.php?remove='+id,
        success: function ( response ) {
          alert( 'removed: '+id );
        },
error: function(e, s){ alert(e.responseText + s) ; }
      });
}

Comment: It has no uncaught syntax error anymore showing in the console, but still the same result no alert but just disparaging. Do you know of any other way of achieving the same result without using onclick?